# IOS swift how can I create a small horizontal line inside a tableView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableView UI and I would like to create a small horizontal line below a certain field inside the TableViewCell for instance this is how it looks, I would like to make the horizontal line right below the Location: Atlanta, GA . This is how the main storyboard looks . I just want to create a thin gray horizontal line below the location field in the prototype cell . Any suggestions would be great . I have found a way to create a line but it was essentially to create a border at the end of the TableCell which is not what I need.

[Emulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S1d5.png)

[ProtoType Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSqse.png)

My code for the TableView is as follows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let mycell = self.StreamsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototype1", for: indexPath) as! HomePage_TableViewCell





        return mycell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return names.count
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this from the Xcode interface builder by adding a View (UIView) control and set the height to 1.

[image]